# React route does not detect nesting routing and ids

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some React routes that when I nest one route inside another, I need to repeat the route path.

To explain, for example:

```
<Route
        path="admin">
        <Switch>
            <Route
                path="admin/specific/:id"
                component={SpecificAdmin} />
            <Route
                exact
                path="admin"
                component={AdminPage}>
            </Route>
            <Route
                exact
                path="admin/edit/new"
                component={EditSpecificAdmin} />
        </Switch>
    </Route>
```

I want a page where I can see the list of items, one for adding a new one and another for looking, editing a specific item. So I thought about the paths `edit/new` and `specific/1`.
So the routes do not detect when I write `specific/1` (the specific id) and not either the admin nesting, so I need to write the admin in each one...

Comment: can you share full code so anyone was able to recreate your issue?

Comment: Basically, what you want is to pass to your nested route '/specific/:id', '/', '/edit/new'. is that so ?

Comment: @ThomasBihan-Poudec yes

Comment: as @tareqAziz answer, you can get some of those intel in props, in one of my project, I created another router for the nested route.
ie: in your project, i would create a AdminRouter component and pass the pass as path={`${match.path}/specific/:id`}, etc

Comment: I think `match.path` will return `/something/:id` which is actually a format, not a partial url of current page. Rather `match.url` will return  `/something/1` or `/something/anything` which can be used as current page's url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tareq aziz said, you can easily have intel in props.

You can create another router to pass easily new value:

```js
// your original component
import AdminRouter from './Admin/Router';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Route path="admin">
     <AdminRouter />     
    </Route>
  );
}

// in ./Admin/Router.js
export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
        <Route 
            exact
            path={`${props.match.path}/specific/:id`}
            component={SpecificAdmin}
        />
        <Route 
            exact
            path={`${props.match.path}`}
            component={AdminPage}
        />
        <Route 
            exact
            path={`${props.match.path}/edit/new`}
            component={EditSpecificAdmin}
        />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

I'm not sure though if the order of the routes are correct.

Comment: That's nice but I'm trying to understand why the route does not do this by itself

Comment: @PichiWuana Because it keeps open to configure by user

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get your current page's url from `props` using `location.pathname` or `match.url`. You can see my image. Then you may add your nested route after that. Hope it will help you

[image]

You may code your path like this way

```
path=`${this.props.location.pathname}/edit/new`

path=`${this.props.location.pathname}/specific/:id`
```